# How can I reference CChannel.h in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, virtual-channel

I'm trying to create a C++ DLL to register with Terminal Services to provide virtual channel functionality. Unfortunately the header `CChannel.h` cannot be found.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, which is targeting Windows SDK 8.0. Sure enough, the required header is missing. However, it is present in the 8.1 `\include\um` directory

Reinstalling the SDK has not changed matters. Manually referencing the 8.1 include directories causes all sorts of issues.

Is there a simple way to get these headers installed under 8.0?

Comment: Is it not included in the Visual Studio include directory? I have a CChannel.h in VS2013's top-level include\... and that file has a 1999 copyright; why would it be missing in past versions?

Comment: Oddly, `cchannel.h` is only missing from Windows SDK 8. It is present in SDK 7 and SDK 8.1 (used as the base for VS2013's default toolset).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a problem [others](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0cc80f05-6914-4139-83b5-f13abb85eee3/some-files-are-missing-in-sdk-8) have encountered before, without a direct resolution.

Oddly, `cchannel.h` is only missing from Windows SDK 8. It is present in SDK 7 and SDK 8.1.

I resolved the problem by using the v110_xp platform toolset. This targets a version of the Windows 7 SDK, but uses the latest compiler (as of VS2012).

VS2012 Update 4 must be installed to access this toolset. More details can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851139.aspx).